# Ruby: How to get a local's and/or a instance varialble's by them self?

Tags: ruby, variables, instance-variables

From example:

```
local_var = "Thanks!"
@instance_var = "Thank you ,too"
```

Then how can I get the `local_var` and `instance_var` part by them self.
I mean weather there is a method maybe called `get_self_name` to get the name of himself:

```
local_var.get_self_name # => 'local_var'
@instance_var.get_self_name # => '@instance_var' or => 'instance_var'

a = 'abc'
a.get_self_name # => 'a'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ irb
>> local_var = "foo"
=> "foo"
>> @instance_var = "bar"
=> "bar"
>> instance_variables
=> ["@prompt", "@instance_var"]
>> local_variables
=> ["_", "local_var"]
```

You also may want to check out `ObjectSpace` module.

The `_` local variable is automatically set to returned value of the last irb statement. @prompt is probably irb's prompt format or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method that can do that. Here are some ways to get around it:

**-1-** Use a hash:

```
local_var = "Thanks!"
@instance_var = "Thank you ,too"
hash = {
  local_var: local_var,
  instance_var: @instance_var
}

hash.index(@instance_var) #=> :instance_var
```

**-2-** use `instance_variables`:

```
local_var = "Thanks!"
@instance_var = "Thank you ,too"

instance_variables.find {|x| instance_variable_get(x) == @instance_var } #=> :instance_var
```

Note that this won't work for local variables.

Comment: It seems that we can get local variable use the second method:
local_var = "Thanks!";
local_variables.find { |x|  eval(x.to_s) == local_var}